# Docker и удаленное ssh подключение

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, devops

При попытке передачи образа через контекст и заранее заготовленными  ssh key на windows происходит вот такая ошибка:

```
$ docker-compose --context remote up -d
[5656] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 72, in main
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 125, in perform_command
File "compose\cli\command.py", line 76, in project_from_options
File "compose\cli\command.py", line 142, in get_project
File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 47, in get_client
File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 174, in docker_client
File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 166, in __init__
File "site-packages\docker\transport\sshconn.py", line 111, in 
__init__
File "site-packages\docker\transport\sshconn.py", line 119, in 
_connect
File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 446, in connect
File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 764, in _auth
File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 735, in _auth
File "site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 586, in 
_key_from_filepath
File "site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 235, in 
from_private_key_file
File "site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
File "site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 175, in 
_from_private_key_file
File "site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 308, in 
_read_private_key_file
File "site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 337, in 
_read_private_key
File "site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 439, in 
_read_private_key_openssh
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: private key file 
is encrypted
```

Сам docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
      container_name: app-springboot-postgresql
image: app-springboot-postgresql
build: /.
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
depends_on:
  - dbpostgres
dbpostgres:
image: postgres
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
environment:
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

Сборка без контекста на локальном пк происходит без ошибок, а вот залить таким способом на мой сервер(raspberry pi) в локальной сети не удается. Ssh подключение работает, по контексту могу посмотреть какие контейнеры крутятся на одноплатнике.
Пользовался статьей "How to deploy on remote Docker hosts with docker-compose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из стека:

> private key file is encrypted

Попробуйте настроить незашифрованый ключ (как минимум, чтоб понять, что проблема в этом).

Ключ может предоставлять ssh-agent (как он на винде -- не знаю).

Можно просто зайти по ssh на сервер и делать всё там.

Можно поднять registry, собирать образ локально, пушить, и запускать compose на сервере. Сделать скрипт для этого.

---

Без registry можно использовать `docker save` и `docker load` через пайп и ssh.